# Difficulty working with ranges and native Excel formulas in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a decent sized worksheet and I want to delete/clear the contents of any empty cells. They don't have a space or any character that I can see (`Len()` returns a zero) and they're being counted by `Counta`.

Here's the macro I've developed, it's supposed to clear the contents of each cell in the selection that has a length of zero:

```
Sub NoNull()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim iLen As Integer
 For Each rCell In Selection
    iLen = WorksheetFunction.Len(Range(rCell))
    If iLen = 0 Then rCell.ClearContents
 Next rCell
End Sub
```

I get an error on this line:

`iLen = WorksheetFunction.Len(Range(rCell))`

I ASSUME it's related to the way I input the rCell into the `Len` formula.

Comment: `iLen = WorksheetFunction.Len(Range(rCell))`-->`iLen = WorksheetFunction.Len(rCell)`

Comment: @simoco Hell, remove WorksheetFunction. as well.

Comment: I've had this issue before. Quite annoying! I solved it without vba: if you select the region you want, do find all without inputting anything on the find box and then Ctrl+A the cells that are found, and hitting delete, removes all the null chars (it worked for me as I describe it for excel 2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are VERY CLOSE:

```
Sub NoNull()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim iLen As Integer
For Each rCell In Selection
    iLen = Len(rCell)
    If iLen = 0 Then rCell.ClearContents
 Next rCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are truly blank then you can do this in a single shot with `SpecialCells`

If the cells may contain formulae that evaluate to a zero length string then your original loop can be improved by turning off `ScreenUpdating` and removing the redunandant `iLen = Len(rCell))`

*for tuly empty cells*

```
Sub NoNull()
On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).ClearContents
End Sub
```

*better loop code*

```
Sub NoNull()
Dim rCell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each rCell In Selection
If Len(rCell.Value) = 0 Then rCell.ClearContents
Next rCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```